# How to search for a string in Java source code and identify in which method it is in?

Tags: java

I need to map the classes and methods of a Java source code that have a specific string inside their implementations.

Translating it in my real example: I need to build a Java application that scans a Java source file searching for a specific string (a database field for example). After finding this string I need to have as an output in which class/method it was found. So, if I have the following code:

```
public class ExampleClass{
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String url = "hello1";
  }
 
  public void function1(){
    String hello2 = "aaaaaa";
  }
}
```

In this case, if I search for `"hello1"` it should return something like: `ExampleClass.main`. And if I search for `"hello2"` it should return: `ExampleClass.function1`

Comment: You might have to write a _Parser_ and a _Lexical Analyzer_ in order to do this, neither of which can be taught to you in one post on StackOverflow.

Comment: Find a library that will breakdown your code into an AST. You can probably google for it.

Comment: Do you really need to build an application, or can you use an IDE to do an interactive search?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, first, I was thinking in analysing the source line by line and identify methods and classes declarations through something like a regex expression.
And unfortunatelly I can't do that inside the IDE because I have to do this analysis for more than 1000 strings inside more than 1000 different java files.

Comment: You can use [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) for such tasks.

Answer (score 1):

From your description it first sounds like you could use a tool like [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) to scan your files. With this solution, you would scan all your files looking for any occurrence of `"hello1"` if this is sufficient for your needs. The output is quite customizable. Using `grep` would look something like this from the command line:

```
$ grep -r "hello1" /home/user/workspace/project/src
```

Given that `/home/user/workspace/project/src` is your project source code root. There are implementations of grep for Windows, just make sure that the version you are using is supporting recursion via the `r` switch, not all implementations do. You can also call `grep` from a Java application by using `System.exec`. Just read the resulting process's output stream for the results.

However, if you really need to parse the source code in order to make sure that the expression you are looking for is a proper `String` literal at the right place you may want to use something like [Eclipse JDT](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/). I reckon that this might however be an overkill for what you are trying to achieve since you then actually need to parse your entire project what is a rather complex job.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, just finding the ocurrence of a string in the source files is not enough, I really need to know in which class/method the string was found. I took a look at the Eclipse JDT but I couldn't figure out how could I use it to find form which method/class a specific string belongs.

Comment: As I said, the JDTs are a quite heavy matter and it will take you some time to figure it all out. To get you started, read this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html - after that, find out how you can use the http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FASTVisitor.html to parse your classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to search and browse source code you can use `OpenGrok`.
You can use this for browse the source code from SVN or any other repository.
We have implemented this Opengrok in our project, its working perfect.

[Read more here.](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/)

Or you can use `grep` command for searching the string data from source code.

```
grep -r /project/src/
```

This unix command will search recursively.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I'll try to use OpenGrok, as I read in it's wiki, it seems like it's possible to solve my problem. Unfortunatelly the grep won't help because it only finds the string, but do not return which methdod/class that string belongs.

Comment: The setup and indexing scripts of OpenGrok are made for Linux, the sourcecode I need to search is on a windows machine and can't be pulled out of there.